# Articolo determinativo in alcune frasi

Tags: word-meaning, sentences

Would you confirm those sentences are correct, regarding the usage of the "articolo determinativo"? Are there some alternatives (some places where it could be written with or without articolo determinativo)?

- **La** Duse fu una grandissima attrice.
- **Il** Dante resta **il** piu grande poeta italiano.
- **Il** Leopardi nacque a Recanati.
- **I** Savoia hanno regnato in Italia dal 1861 al 1946.
- **L**'anno prossimo avremo **il** professor Rossi.
- **Il** bidello Gerardo è un brav'uomo.
- **La** Sicilia e **la** Sardegna sono due maggiori isole di Mediterraneo.
- **La** prossima estate andremo in vacanza a Ischia.
- Enna è **la** piu alta città capoluogo d'Italia.
- **Il** Tevere nasce da monte Fumaiolo.
- **La** Napoli settecentesca era una **delle** piu importanti citta europee.
- Don Abbondio è un personaggio **dei** Promessi Sposi **del** Manzoni.
- **L'** anno venturo faremo un viaggio **negli** Stati Uniti e **nel** Canada.
- **Dalle** Filippine abbiamo volato **nel** Giappone.
- **Il** lago di Garda bagna tre regioni.
- Francesco è **il** ragazzo piu alto **della** classe.
- Sono andato a passeggio con (**la**) Gisella.
- Ivan **il** Terribile fu zar di (o **della**) Russia **nel** sedicesimo (XVI) secolo.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Comment: This website is not to have one's exercises corrected, @kiriloff. Having a jumble of 18 sentences all together is useless. Far more useful, for you and for future users of the site, would be if you isolate one or more specific issues you might have (for instance: articles before given names of people, or before places, or together with prepositions and so on), look for previous existing questions on the topic and, if none clarifies your doubts, ask separate, specific questions.

Comment: You can see in our [list of off-topic questions](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): 'Proofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sentences should be corrected:

- Dante resta il più grande poeta italiano.
- (Il) Leopardi nacque a Recanati.
- La Sicilia e la Sardegna sono le due maggiori isole del Mediterraneo. or better *La Sicilia e la Sardegna sono le isole più grandi del Mediterraneo.*
- Il Tevere nasce dal monte Fumaiolo.
- La Napoli settecentesca era una delle più importanti città europee.
- L' anno venturo faremo un viaggio negli Stati Uniti e in Canada.
- Dalle Filippine abbiamo volato in Giappone.
- Francesco è il ragazzo più alto della classe.

Comment: Veramente si dice "il Dante"?

Comment: you corrected in the question, right?

Comment: No, non si dice “il Dante”, @Charo, perché è un prenome. Si può dire invece “l'Alighieri”.

Comment: Potresti modificare il riferimento a "il Dante", per favore?

Comment: @Charo Grazie ho corretto la mia risposta, sono stato tratto in inganno dal fatto che Dante a differenza della maggior parte degli altri personaggi celebri è indicato spesso con solo il nome e non con il cognome. Anche se tecnicamente è scorretto nel nord Italia spesso si antepone un articolo ai nomi propri nel parlato/scritto comune, in frasi del tipo `La Marta è una brava alunna.`, che per abitudine non mi suona male

Comment: Per favore, evita `questo tipo di formato`